# How to pass efficiently large block iterator enumerable through an http service?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Block iterator is a very interesting feature in C#, but when it have to pass through an HTTP service, you have to serialize it at some point.

Example :

```
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Something>> Get() {
     return _provider.ReadLargeList() ; // with large list implemented with a block iterator 
}
```

Are there common design patterns to solve this without bringing everything in memory?

Comment: Isn't the list already in memory?  c# is managed and you cannot use pointers to save memory.  Use c++ instead.  HTTP has special character so adding data to body is not the best way of going.  Instead add a binary attachment to the http so you do not have to serialize and deserialize.

Comment: list is from a filesystem with a block iterator

Comment: You can upload the file.  If you send a list object than it is in memory.